# Log in IIS logs the server variables set in the application code (Capture Web API Route)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I would like to add custom server variables created in ASP.Net Web API code and log these in IIS logs. IIS logs allow logging custom request, response headers and server variables. This way, the client's custom header can be logged, server response header can be logged, but if server code wants to log custom detail in IIS log but not make it a part of the response header, I felt server variables should do that.

The following code adds to the server variables collection ok, but on extended logging in IIS to capture this variable, it does not show up.

```
    public class TestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var variables = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper) request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.ServerVariables;
        variables.Set("BptTime", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will help.

**Post Edit**: updated the title to indicate the real requirement was to capture web api route, missed this when posting originally.

Comment: did you get any error message or exception when you try to generate log? use iis failed request tracing or windows event viewer to get more idea about the issue.

Comment: you could use [Advanced Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging) extension.

Comment: No, there are no exceptions, so nothing in event log, and I did not see any additional info in the failed request log. The new key value is added to the server variable collection in the .Net code, can see that during debugging, just does not show up in the extended log (or advanced log as you pointed out) to include the server variable

Comment: Could you share the update log code?

Comment: There is no code to add to log. In IIS, we can navigate to the website -> logging -> Select fields (with format w3c), Add Field -> Add a field with source type server variable. But I accidentally came across the solution while reading up on server variables, so let me add that as the answer. I guess I should have been more thorough on my reading the first time around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a little more reading on Server variables took me to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90) where it is mentioned:

> HTTP_< HeaderName>
>   The value stored in the header . Any header other than those listed in this table **must be preceded by "HTTP_"** in order for the ServerVariables collection to retrieve its value. This is useful for retrieving custom headers.

Now, this documentation is mentioned as IIS 6.0 but it holds up on later version of IIS too. I tried this and my variable changed to

```
            variables.Set("HTTP_BptTime", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and the IIS log logs this field correctly

```
2019-09-05 01:13:08 ::1 GET /api/values/2 - 9010 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+/76.0.3809.132+Safari/537.36 - localhost:9010 200 0 0 5 - 9010 - 09/05/2019+06:43:08
```

Now, logging time was just an example, but my real need was with logging Web API Route so that I can review IIS logs better for performance characteristics of different routes.

The code changes slightly to:

```
        if (request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request)?.Values["MS_SubRoutes"] is IHttpRouteData[] candidateRoutes)
        {
            var routeTemplate = candidateRoutes.First().Route.RouteTemplate;

            // Add to Server Variables - so IIS can log the route too
            var variables = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables;
            variables.Set("HTTP_WebApiRoute", routeTemplate);
        }
```

and IIS log has the route information now:

```
2019-09-05 03:36:24 ::1 GET /api/values/35 9010 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0/76.0.3809.132+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 2093 630 13 - - - api/values/{id}
```

Hope this helps someone else too and do let me know if there is a better way.